# Weird Regex behavior in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract some alfanumeric expressions out of a longer word in C# using regular expressions. For example I have the word "FooNo12Bee". I use the the following regular expression code, which returns me two matches, "No12" and "No" as results:

```
alfaNumericWord = "FooNo12Bee";
Match m = Regex.Match(alfaNumericWord, @"(No|Num)\d{1,3}");
```

If I use the following expression, without paranthesis and without any alternative for "No" it works the way I am expecting, it returns only "No12":

```
alfaNumericWord = "FooNo12Bee";
Match m = Regex.Match(alfaNumericWord, @"No\d{1,3}");
```

What is the difference between these two expressions, why using paranthesis results in a redundant result for "No"?

Comment: [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - it's not *redundant* you explicitly asked it to capture it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parenthesis in regex are capture groups; meaning what's in between the paren will be captured and stored as a capture group.

If you don't want a capture group but still need a group for the alternation, use a non-capture group instead; by putting `?:` after the first paren:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(alfaNumericWord, @"(?:No|Num)\d{1,3}");
```

Usually, if you don't want to change the regex for some reason, you can simply retrieve the group 0 from the match to get only the whole match (and thus ignore any capture groups); in your case, using `m.Groups[0].Value`.

Last, you can improve the efficiency of the regex by a notch using:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(alfaNumericWord, @"N(?:o|um)\d{1,3}");
```

Comment: Ah I see, I did not know that using paranthesis has the explicit job to capture subgroups, I only used them in order to capture alternative words. Is there any other way to look for alternative words without using paranthesis?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici You could use the longer alternative: `No\d{1,3}|Num\d{1,3}` but... that's a little too repetitive I believe :) And otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

i can't explain how they call it, but it is because putting parentheses around it is creating a new group. it is well explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

> Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses
>   also create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the
>   string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the
>   parentheses.
>
> The regex Set(Value)? matches Set or SetValue. In the first case, the
>   first (and only) capturing group remains empty. In the second case,
>   the first capturing group matches Value.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the parentheses are creating a group.  You can remove the group with `?:` like so
`Regex.Match(alfaNumericWord, @"(?:No|Num)\d{1,3}");`